# How to fix windows 10 crash when opening Android Emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

My computer kept crashing to a blue screen whenever I started a newly created virtual device(VD) with an updated API.

First, I deleted an old virtual device which was working perfectly well before creating the new one. The new VD was defined to a Pixel 3a (Play Store), R release with API 30 and was set with modified RAM, internal, and external storage. My expectation was for it to work fine as the old one but whenever I started the VD, it kept crashing my computer.

Tried setting generic values for the storage and RAM and made sure to have updated SDK platforms and tools but still kept crashing when I started the VD.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that the Intel HAXM option is checked and installed in your SDK tools.

[image: Make sure that the Intel HAXM is checked and installed in the settings.]

Comment: After viewing other complicated solutions - this worked like a charm. reasonable and simple

Comment: Solve the issue.Thank you